# how to stop button.performClick();

Tags: android, click, handler

i am sory, how to stop `button.performClick();`

when i run my program, i call `button.performClick();` , but button click not stop in the statement. and my source :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            button.performClick();
        }
    },(3*1000));
    if (accuracy<=15){
        button.setClickable(false);
    }
```

i want if accuracy <= 15 tombol stop `performClick();` . How true syntax to stop `performClick();`
because i make `button.setClickable(false);` is false. whereas condition statement is true.

Comment: Where does the accuracy come from? (inside the if statement)

Comment: we defined statement accuracy is true, because my code is long..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (accuracy<=15){
               return;
             }
            button.performClick();
        }
    },(3*1000));
```